# Determine Card Number from ATR in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard, emv

I am using an ACS card reader. I have a contactless VISA card. By reading the card I get the following hex ATR information:

```
3B 6E 00 00 80 31 80 66 B1 A3 01 01 21 0A 83 00 90 00
```

From the above ATR, how I can detect the card number and type?

Comment: You'd have to look at the specification for your card reader to understand what those bytes mean.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

That ATR (answer-to-reset) does not contain such information. In fact, since your card is a contactless card (ISO/IEC 14443-4), it does not even have an ATR, but an ATS (answer-to-select), which is the contactless "equivalent" (at least in terms of contained information) of an ATR.

Instead, you would need to exchange APDUs (ISO/IEC 7816-4) with your card to get further information from it. Since you refer to VISA, your card probably speaks the EMV protocol for contactless cards (see http://www.emvco.com/).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you tell me how to exchange APDUs?

Comment: @mdmuzahidulislam No, not with the information you provided. What reader do you use?

Comment: I am using this one http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/303/acr32-mobilemate-card-reader/

Comment: @Md.MuzahidulIslam You may want to start with the demo app from the ACS website, read the manuals, and then *ask a separate question* if you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

ATR = Answer to reset, is hex string getting from the card as a response of Reset command sent by the IFD/Card_Reader. It tells about card properties like-

```
- card speed
- protocol (T=0, T=1) supported by card 
- etc..
```

If you need to get the card number/ PAN from the card you need to fire Read_Record command to get the value from the card. Sequence will be like:-

- Fire PPSE command ( if your card support PPSE installed in it)

Contactless PPSE:

```
  00A404000E325041592E5359532E444446303100 // ppse command
```

it will give you the AID of application installed in the card, in your case it will be

> A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 //VISA AID

Select application

```
00 a4 04 00 07  A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 00
```

then Fire GPO command , it will give you AFL detail. Next you need to fire Read Record command and search for PAN Tag ( 5A).

this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394699/unable-to-identify-afl-on-a-smart-card) post can be useful for you..hope this information helps you to get the card number/PAN as you are looking for.