# How to read response from a credit card over NFC

Tags: android, xamarin, nfc, contactless-smartcard, emv

I need to get the card number from a credit card using NFC and then convert it to a proper string.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private static readonly string MASTERCARD_AID = "A0000000041010";
// ISO-DEP command HEADER for selecting an AID.
// Format: [Class | Instruction | Parameter 1 | Parameter 2]
private static readonly string SELECT_APDU_HEADER = "00A40400";
// "OK" status word sent in response to SELECT AID command (0x9000)
private static readonly byte[] SELECT_OK_SW = { (byte)0x90, (byte)0x00 };

// Weak reference to prevent retain loop. mAccountCallback is responsible for exiting
// foreground mode before it becomes invalid (e.g. during onPause() or onStop()).
private WeakReference<AccountCallback> mAccountCallback;

public interface AccountCallback
{
    void OnAccountRecieved(string account);
}

public LoyaltyCardReader(WeakReference<AccountCallback> accountCallback)
{
    mAccountCallback = accountCallback;
}
/**
 * Callback when a new tag is discovered by the system.
 *
 * <p>Communication with the card should take place here.
 *
 * @param tag Discovered tag
 */
public void OnTagDiscovered(Tag tag)
{
    IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.Get(tag);
    if (isoDep != null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Connect to the remote NFC device
            isoDep.Connect();
            // Build SELECT AID command for our loyalty card service.
            // This command tells the remote device which service we wish to communicate with.
            byte[] command = BuildSelectApdu(MASTERCARD_AID);
            // Send command to remote device
            byte[] result = isoDep.Transceive(command);
            // If AID is successfully selected, 0x9000 is returned as the status word (last 2
            // bytes of the result) by convention. Everything before the status word is
            // optional payload, which is used here to hold the account number.
            int resultLength = result.Length; //should be 89
            byte[] statusWord = { result[resultLength - 2], result[resultLength - 1] };
            byte[] payload = new byte[resultLength - 2];
            Array.Copy(result, payload, resultLength - 2);
            bool arrayEquals = SELECT_OK_SW.Length == statusWord.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < SELECT_OK_SW.Length && i < statusWord.Length && arrayEquals; i++)
            {
                arrayEquals = (SELECT_OK_SW[i] == statusWord[i]);
                if (!arrayEquals)
                    break;
            }
            if (arrayEquals)
            {
                //takes out cardname
                //int lengthWanted = 58;
                //byte[] newRes = new byte[resultLength - lengthWanted];
                //byte[] cardname = new byte[newRes.Length - 15]; 
                //Array.Copy(payload, newRes, resultLength - lengthWanted);
                //Array.Copy(payload, 16, cardname, 0, cardname.Length);

                // The remote NFC device will immediately respond with its stored account number
                string accountNumber = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payload);
                //string accountNumber = ByteArrayToHexString(payload);

                // Inform CardReaderFragment of received account number
                AccountCallback accountCallback;
                if (mAccountCallback.TryGetTarget(out accountCallback))
                {
                    accountCallback.OnAccountRecieved(accountNumber);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hmm: " + e);
            throw e;
            //Toast.MakeText(ctx, "hmmm: " + e, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Build APDU for SELECT AID command. This command indicates which service a reader is
 * interested in communicating with. See ISO 7816-4.
 *
 * @param aid Application ID (AID) to select
 * @return APDU for SELECT AID command
 */
public static byte[] BuildSelectApdu(string aid)
{
    // Format: [CLASS | INSTRUCTION | PARAMETER 1 | PARAMETER 2 | LENGTH | DATA]
    return HexStringToByteArray(SELECT_APDU_HEADER + (aid.Length / 2).ToString("X2") + aid);
}

/**
* Utility class to convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string.
*
* @param bytes Bytes to convert
* @return String, containing hexadecimal representation.
*/

public static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes)
{
    var hex = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    return hex.ToString();
}

/**
 * Utility class to convert a hexadecimal string to a byte string.
 *
 * <p>Behavior with input strings containing non-hexadecimal characters is undefined.
 *
 * @param s String containing hexadecimal characters to convert
 * @return Byte array generated from input
 */
private static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string s)
{
    int len = s.Length;
    if (len % 2 == 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Hex string must have even number of characters");
    }
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2]; //Allocate 1 byte per 2 hex characters
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
    {
        ushort val, val2;
        // Convert each chatacter into an unsigned integer (base-16)
        try
        {
            val = (ushort)Convert.ToInt32(s[i].ToString() + "0", 16);
            val2 = (ushort)Convert.ToInt32("0" + s[i + 1].ToString(), 16);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            continue;
        }

        data[i / 2] = (byte)(val + val2);
    }
    return data;
}
```

I can extract the card type, but the rest of the result is gibberish, like boxed questionmarks and so on. I have tried to read all I could find on that subject, but I simply don't get it! :(

I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

I can't remember where I got it but most of the code is taken from a great example where the author used another phone as emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your card actually is a MasterCard (or actually pretty much any EMV payment card), the card won't return its card number (actually: primary account number, PAN) in response to the application selection (SELECT) command. Instead, you would need to query the card for its data files and extract the number from those files.

Thus, you would first SELECT the MasterCard application by its AID:

```
result = isoDep.Transceive(HexStringToByteArray("00A404007A000000004101000"));
```

Next, you would typically issue a GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command (see [Unable to identify AFL on a smart card](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37396191/2425802)) in order to discover the location of the data records. However, you could also skip this step and try to read records by a brute-force approach.

Reading records with a brute-force approach could look something like this:

```
for (int sfi = 1; sfi < 10; ++sfi ) {
    for (int record = 1; record < 10; ++record) {
        byte[] cmd = HexStringToByteArray("00B2000400");
        cmd[2] = (byte)(record & 0x0FF)
        cmd[3] |= (byte)((sfi << 3) & 0x0F8);
        result = isoDep.Transceive(cmd);
        if ((result != null) && (result.Length >=2)) {
            if ((result[result.Length - 2] == (byte)0x90) && (result[result.Length - 1] == (byte)0x00)) {
                // file exists and contains data
                byte[] data = Arrays.CopyOf(result, result.Length - 2);
                // TODO: parse data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would then need to search the data returned for each record in order to find the data object containing the PAN. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34527272/2425802) on how to decode TLV encoded data objects. You can find an online TLV parser [here](http://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/). The PAN is typically encoded in a data object with the tag 0x5A (see [here](http://www.emvlab.org/emvtags/?description=pan)).

Note that the PAN that you can read over NFC *may* differ from the PAN printed on the card.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is not secure (in terms of cryptography, so it's prone to fake cards). For a verified recognition of a card (and its PAN) you have to do a complete EMV transaction that involves either an online authorization or offline data authentication. You could perform this as a so called "0-value transaction" (a payment transaction with amount 0), but then you have to code the complete payment process!

Comment: @Dominik Correct. It definitely requires more than reading the PAN in order to authenticate a card.

Comment: Thanks for input, i can also add an interesting source that i used, this java project: com.github.devnied.emvnfccard!!

Comment: @Kalkunen where you successful to use the mentioned project in xamarin?